# Ranking a table in Excel

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, rank

I have a question on Excel that I hope someone can help with. I am working on a table that has scores entered that need to be ranked, normally this is easy enough BUT I need to rank by person and also just use their top 3 or 4 scores.

So for example if you have a football team and every game they play, each player that scores in the match will be entered on the table with how many goals/points they score in the game and so on throughout the season. It is possible that the same players will be entered every time they play, what I'm looking to do is, on a list of all players that have scored in a season is to retrieve and sum up their top 4 scores.

Is there a formula for this? Is it possible?

[image: Example of Table]

As an example, How do I best find each persons top 4 scores?

Comment: Take a look at `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any one formula for this, but I was able to get what you want by doing the following:

1. Add a column named **Rank** and a column named **ScoreTotal**
2. Sort your table by **Player** then **Score**. Ignore the **Game** or any other columns. Make sure to sort **Score** from Largest to Smallest.
3. In the **Rank** Column, add this formula: `IF(A2<>A1,1,D1+1)` and fill it down the column.
4. In the **ScoreTotal** column add this formula: `=IF(D2=1,C2,IF(D2<=4,E1+C2,0))` and fill it down the column.
5. Create a pivot table choosing only **Player** and **ScoreTotal** Columns. In the values section of the pivot table, choose "Max of ScoreTotal".

Here's what I got with my sample data:

[image]

Comment: ...for those of us with older versions of Excel.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought of using pivot tables but I have to do this for multiple sports & games in 1 workbook and didn't want it to be too messy, I thought there might be some formula out there like "rankif" or something like that that I haven't heard of because each table of information will be updated continuously. I thought a formula might be easier but looks like pivots might be the only option.